# MvxDialogFragmentPresentation enter animation

Tags: mvvmcross

I want my `MyDialogFragment` to slide in from the bottom of the screen when it appears:

```
[MvxDialogFragmentPresentation(enterAnimation: Resource.Animator.anim_enter_bottom)]
[Register(nameof(MyDialogFragment))]
public class MyDialogFragment : MvxDialogFragment<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyDialogFragment()
    {

    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_my, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

anim_enter_bottom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:toYDelta="300" />
</set>
```

When I show it:

```
await Navigator.Navigate<MyViewModel, MyModel>(new MyModel());
```

It shows, but it does not slide up from the bottom. It simply appears in the middle of the screen.

Comment: The enter and exit animations are not currently implemented for dialogs according to a recently submitted [Github issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3775).

Comment: `MvxFrameControl` doesn't seem to work in dialogs either.